# Neovim: Making a function that checks the beginning of line and acts depending on it

Tags: neovim, key-bindings, autocmd, lua

Extra details,
The whole code:

```lua
local obsidianSettingsGroup = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('Obsidian Group', { clear = true })
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('FileType', {
  pattern = {'markdown'}, 
  callback = function()

    function entitle()
      local current_line = vim.api.nvim_get_current_line()
      if current_line[0] == '#' then 
        return "I#<Esc>A<Esc>"
      else 
        return "I# <Esc>A<Esc>"
      end 
    end

    local keymap = vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap
    local opts = {noremap = true, silent}
    keymap(0, 'n', '<C-S-p>', ':ObsidianWorkspace<CR>',   opts)
    keymap(0, 'n', '<C-p>',   ':ObsidianQuickSwitch<CR>', opts)
    keymap(0, 'n', '=',       entitle(),                  opts)
  end,
  group = obsidianSettingsGroup,
})
```

So the goal is to check if the line starts with `#`:

- if yes, add `#` to it,
- if not, add `#` and a space after it.

Everything in the code works except the condition, which always returns false. Mind you it still runs, it just gives me the wrong thing.

I have checked around the internet for various things but didn't find anything like this, or rather everybody who went about matching and replacing used very similar code but never in conditionals, dunno what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```lua
local obsidianSettingsGroup = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('Obsidian Group', { clear = true })
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('FileType', {
  pattern = {'markdown'}, 
  callback = function()

    function entitle()
      print("bob")
      local current_line = vim.api.nvim_get_current_line()

      if string.sub(current_line, 1, 1) == '#' then 
          vim.api.nvim_command("normal! I#")
      else 
          vim.api.nvim_command("normal! I# ")
      end 
    end

    local keymap = vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap
    local opts = {noremap = true, silent = true, callback = entitle}
    keymap(0, "n", "<C-s>", "", opts)
  end,
  group = obsidianSettingsGroup,
})
```

Here are three remarks about the original code that lead me to a working solution.

To compare the string you have to use `string.sub(current_line, 1, 1) == '#'` instead of just `current_line[0] == '#'`

If you intend to use a callback it has to be set in the `opts` argument and not as a right hand side (`rhs` argument).

The `callback` argument is not like the Vim `<expr>` it is function that intend to modify the buffer itself (the return value is discarded).

Comment: It didn't work, neither first form nor second form.

Comment: I have corrected the answer. This one I tested and should work fine.

Comment: I am very sorry for my rudeness, but it is still not working :/